# If $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$, $f'$ continuous, $f'(x)+(f(x))^2+1\geq 0$, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=-\infty$, then $b-a=$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

$$\text{If } f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}, f'\text{ continuous,}\\ f'(x)+(f(x))^2+1\geq 0,\ \forall x\in(a,b), \ \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty,\ \lim_{x\to b}f(x)=-\infty,\\ \text{then } b-a=?$$

How would one solve this problem? I don't really know where to start from. I have thought of a Lagrange's or Cauchy's theorems, but they obviously do not apply to $f$. The only things I found and think is useful is that if $f$ is derivable, then it is continuous, and, given those two limits, then $Imf=(-\infty, \infty)$. Further, because those limits are both infinite, then maybe the limits of $f'(x)$ in $a,b$ must also be $\infty$, respectively $-\infty$. Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: I think $f(x)=-\tan(rx)$ works for $0<r\leq 1$ on the bounds $(-\pi/2r, \pi /2r)$. But then $b-a=\frac{\pi}{r}$ which goes to infinity as $r\to 0^{+}$. Is there something else in the question?

Comment: No, I have transcribed the entire question. However, I can say for certain the answer has $\pi$, because all the 6 answers given by the book to pick include $\pi$ (by this I mean all exercises are multiple choice, of course, the book says only 1 is correct at the back, but without any clues or explanations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can prove that $b-a\geq \pi$. Suppose we have some function and interval such that $b-a<\pi$. Then

$$1\geq \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2+1}=\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(f(x))$$

Integrating we have

$$b-a=\int_a^b dx > \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon}\left[\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(f(x))\right]dx=\arctan(f(b-\epsilon))-\arctan(f(a+\epsilon))$$

for small $\epsilon$. Since

$$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=-\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=\infty$$

and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\arctan(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that

$$\arctan(f(b-\epsilon))>\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi-b+a}{2}=\frac{b-a}{2}$$

$$\arctan(f(a+\epsilon))<-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi-b+a}{2}=-\frac{b-a}{2}$$

Then the inequality becomes

$$\arctan(f(b-\epsilon))-\arctan(f(a+\epsilon))>\frac{b-a}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow b-a>b-a$$

a contraction. We conclude that $b-a\geq \pi$. Since we have an example where $b-a=\pi$ (take $f(x)=-\tan(x)$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$) we may conclude that this bound is tight.